# How to show loading message in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview and i want to show "loading... " message or spinning circle while the recycler is populated with data from json.
This is the code for my recycler :

```
 arrayList = new ArrayList<>();      
    adapter = new ListAdapterGrupat2(this, arrayList, Comanda.class);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://mysite/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    service = retrofit.create(API.class);  

    if (myuser.equals("1")) {
        service.getComenzileMele(user).enqueue(listener);

    } else {
        service.getComenziGrupat().enqueue(listener);
    }
}
Callback<List<CustomObject>> listener = new Callback<List<CustomObject>>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<CustomObject>> call, Response<List<CustomObject>> response) {
        arrayList.clear();
        arrayList.addAll(response.body());
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<CustomObject>> call, Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(ComenziGrupatActivity.this, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();           
    }
};
```

> This is the adapter :

```
public class ListAdapterGrupat2 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapterGrupat2.ViewHolder> {   

public ListAdapterGrupat2(Context context, ArrayList<CustomObject> arrayList, Class<?> cls) {        
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_programarigrupat, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    CustomObject obj = arrayList.get(position);
    holder.item2.setText(obj.getItem2());

}
```

Comment: We need your Adapter code to do it.

Comment: @deathangel908 where should i make it visible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add [ProgressBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) to your class and layout (near your recicleView). If you want text: add LinearLayout and place there `ProgressBar` and `TextView` (trigger visibility on linearLayout):

```
ProgressBar bar;
```

Show progressBar when you're making a request and hide recicleView:

```
bar.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
recicleView.setVisibility(GONE);     
service.getComenzileMele(user).enqueue(listener);
```

Hide progressBar when request is finished and restore recicleView:

```
Callback<List<CustomObject>> listener = new Callback<List<CustomObject>>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<CustomObject>> call, Response<List<CustomObject>> response) {
        bar.setVisibility(GONE);
        recicleView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<CustomObject>> call, Throwable t) {
        bar.setVisibility(GONE);
        recicleView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);         
    }
};
```